# Getting "Error: 8 RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED: Sent message larger than max (2217 vs. 15)" from hyperledger fabric

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, grpc

I am trying to execute "balance-transfer" fabric sample provided in https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples.git, and when it is executing following code from testAPIs.sh it is getting GRPC max limit error.
Please suggest how I can fix it.

### Code in testAPIs.sh

```
`curl -s -X POST \
  http://localhost:4000/channels \
  -H "authorization: Bearer $ORG1_TOKEN" \
  -H "content-type: application/json" \
  -d '{
    "channelName":"mychannel",
    "channelConfigPath":"../artifacts/channel/mychannel.tx"
}'`
```

### Error

```
[2018-05-11 16:34:15.115] [ERROR] Create-Channel - Error: 8 RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED: Sent message larger than max (2217 vs. 15)
    at createStatusError (/home/amandai/blockchain/fabric-samplesV1/fabric-samples-1.1/balance-transfer/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:64:15)
    at ClientDuplexStream._emitStatusIfDone (/home/amandai/blockchain/fabric-samplesV1/fabric-samples-1.1/balance-transfer/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:270:19)
    at ClientDuplexStream._readsDone (/home/amandai/blockchain/fabric-samplesV1/fabric-samples-1.1/balance-transfer/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:236:8)
    at readCallback (/home/amandai/blockchain/fabric-samplesV1/fabric-samples-1.1/balance-transfer/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:296:12)
(node:16186) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 4): Error: Failed to initialize the channel: Error: 8 RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED: Sent message larger than max (2217 vs. 15)
```

Comment: After updating the fabric samples, it is working fine now. Can you tell me where was the code modification?

Answer (score 2):

You can set:

```
grpcOptions:
  grpc-max-send-message-length: -1
```

In the network config.yaml on your peer or connecting client.

Answer (score 2):

In the updated version of "balance-transfer" application, they have removed the `grpc-max-send-message-length` from `grpcOptions` listed under Orderer in [network-config.yaml](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release-1.2/balance-transfer/artifacts/network-config.yaml)

Earlier the value was set to 15 which was causing this issue.